# Date Format with Locale

Tags: java, android, date, locale, datetime-format

I want to display date according to each country's date format. I have tried many ways finally I found this example

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/DateFormatwithLocale.htm

Which gives the perfect output of what I meant. Some countries like *Germany* won't use **12hr** formats instead they uses **24 hr** formats with **no AM/PM**. While some countries like *US* uses 12hr formats.

But I found that while running  this java class it returns the correct output as expected but while running this inside an Android project it returns something like this

```
I/System.out: Locale: en_US
I/System.out: Jan 23, 2018 5:26:41 AM
I/System.out: Jan 23, 2018 5:26:41 AM
I/System.out: Jan 23, 2018 5:26:41 AM
I/System.out: Jan 23, 2018 5:26:41 AM
I/System.out: Jan 23, 2018 5:26:41 AM
I/System.out: Locale: de_DE
I/System.out: 23.01.2018 5:26:41 vorm.
I/System.out: 23.01.2018 5:26:41 vorm.
I/System.out: 23.01.2018 5:26:41 vorm.
I/System.out: 23.01.2018 5:26:41 vorm.
I/System.out: 23.01.2018 5:26:41 vorm.
```

In case of Locale: en_US it is as expected but in case of Locale: de_DE it is expected not to have that “vorm.”.

Could anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: 5:26 AM is the same as 5:26 in 24h format, 5:26 PM would be 17:26 in 24h format

Comment: But I don't want that 'vorm' to get displayed. if in case of 5.30 pm it will display 17.30 nachm, I just need it to be 17.30

Comment: "nachm." is German for PM, "vorm." for "AM". The behaviour is as expected! Take a look at this link, http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/de-DE/index.html

Comment: Not being a native German speaker I very much agree that *vorm.* for AM and *nach,.* for PM looks odd and very unGerman (how do you capitalize *Ungerman*?) I too would expect just 5:26:41 (or 17:26:41 if the time was in PM).

Comment: @OleV.V. Yeah you are correct..

Comment: There is [an interesting answer to a duplicate question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48662449/5772882).

Comment: Oyye.. Thanks for the update @OleV.V. , Thats one is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.. :) Thanks  Ole V.V.

Here it is : [Java DateFormat.SHORT in Android not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48636884/java-dateformat-short-in-android-not-working-as-expected/48662449#48662449)

Answer (score 1):

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 1, 23, 5, 26, 41);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
            .withLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
    System.out.println(dateTime.format(formatter));
```

Prints

```
23.01.2018, 05:26:41
```

Not tested on Android, though, but I believe the result will be the same.

### java.time

The `Date` and `DateFormat` classes used on the java2s page you are linking to are long outdated, and the latter in particular also notoriously troublesome. For this reason alone I recommend you stop using them and start using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, instead. It’s so much nicer to work with.

Can you do that on Android? You certainly can. I am told that `java.time` is built in on newer Android devices. For older devices, add ThreeTenABP to your project (see the links at the bottom) and make sure to import `org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime`, `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter` and `org.threeten.bp.format.FormatStyle`. Then it will all work.

### What went wrong?

Java picks up its locale information from different sources. It varies between desktop Java and Android Java, it may even vary between Android devices, and it varies between Java versions. Without any guarantee, I think that `java.time` is more stable in this respect than the old classes were.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: V.V , Hey it works perfectly even in android. But the problem is that it can only target to API 26 or more, that means only in Android O or higher. But my project's min API is 21. So I can't use this.

Comment: I think you can use ThreeTenABP on level 21. Am I mistaken? Not my home field, sorry…

Answer (score 0):

This is native behaviour in java JDK.

Depends on the valid Locale you pass, JDK provide the time with formatted date.

Returns a new [`DateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) instance which formats date with the given formatting style for the specified locale.

```
Parameters:
style the given formatting style. Either one of DateFormat.SHORT, 
DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.LONG, or DateFormat.FULL.
locale the desired locale.
Returns: a date formatter.
Throws: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException if style is invalid, or if locale isn't 
one of the locales returned from getAvailableLocales().
java.lang.NullPointerException if locale is null
See also: java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance(int,java.util.Locale)
```

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/text/spi/DateFormatProvider.java#DateFormatProvider.getTimeInstance%28int%2Cjava.util.Locale%29

Comment: If it is the native behavior then why it is resulting 2 different output in java and android?