# Format date and time with seconds while using user's locale settings

Tags: java, android, datetime, kotlin

I am trying to display date and time including seconds BUT formatted according to user's locale settings. So if an action happened on the 5th of March 2020 at 14:47:51, in US it should be displayed as `03/05/2020 14:47:51` while in UK it would be `05/03/2020 14:47:51`, in Poland `05.03.2020, 14:47:51`, in Czechia `5.3.2020 14:47:51` etc.

I am able to display it without seconds by:

```
DateUtils.formatDateTime(
            context,
            event.time,
         DateUtils.FORMAT_24HOUR or DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME or DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR or DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE or DateUtils.FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE
        )
```

But there is no constant to display seconds.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date Format with Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48398572/date-format-with-locale)

Comment: USA use 12 hour time format

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter localizedFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT, FormatStyle.MEDIUM);
    
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime
            .of(2020, 3, 5, 14, 47, 51, 123456789, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    
    System.out.println(dateTime.format(localizedFormatter));
```

My desktop Java 11 gets its locale data from [CLDR, the Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository), used by default [as of Java 9](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252). These data don’t agree with your expectations in all cases. Output in different locales is:

```
en-US  3/5/20, 2:47:51 PM
en-GB  05/03/2020, 14:47:51
pl-PL  05.03.2020, 14:47:51
cs-CZ  05.03.20 14:47:51
```

See this run live on Java 12 [at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/N4C0eK).

Output on Android may differ, though, please see for yourself if you don’t get satisfactory results.

The two-argument `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime()` takes one argument for date style and one for time style. Each can be short, medium, long or full.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.